# Shader intrinsic asfloat from bool disappeared?

Tags: directx, shader, direct3d, hlsl

Compiling this pixel shader:

```
float4 main() : SV_TARGET
{
    bool4 b = bool4(true, false, true, false);
    return asfloat(b);
}
```

with the command `fxc.exe test.hlsl /T ps_5_0` fails:

```
Microsoft (R) Direct3D Shader Compiler 6.3.9600.16384 (using C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64\D3DCOMPILER_47.dll)
Copyright (C) 2013 Microsoft. All rights reserved.

test.hlsl(13,12-21): error X3013: 'asfloat': no matching 1 parameter intrinsic function
test.hlsl(13,12-21): error X3013: Possible intrinsic functions are:
test.hlsl(13,12-21): error X3013:     asfloat(float|half|int|uint)

compilation failed; no code produced
```

It works with an older version of the shader compiler though:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Utilities\bin\x64\fxc.exe" /T ps_5_0 test.hlsl
Microsoft (R) Direct3D Shader Compiler 9.29.952.3111
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2002-2009. All rights reserved.

//
// Generated by Microsoft (R) HLSL Shader Compiler 9.29.952.3111
//
//
//   fxc /T ps_5_0 a.hlsl
//
//
//
// Input signature:
//
// Name                 Index   Mask Register SysValue Format   Used
// -------------------- ----- ------ -------- -------- ------ ------
// no Input
//
// Output signature:
//
// Name                 Index   Mask Register SysValue Format   Used
// -------------------- ----- ------ -------- -------- ------ ------
// SV_TARGET                0   xyzw        0   TARGET  float   xyzw
//
ps_5_0
dcl_globalFlags refactoringAllowed
dcl_output o0.xyzw
mov o0.xyzw, l(1.000000,0,1.000000,0)
ret
// Approximately 2 instruction slots used
```

The [MSDN page on asfloat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509570(v=vs.85).aspx) does not mention that this changed, and lists the `bool` overload.

Is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong? Was this intrinsic removed intentionally? What should I use instead? (I actually used it in combination with `asfloat(all(...))`.)

Comment: VS 2013 Update 5 and VS 2015 comes with the Windows 8.1 SDK Spring 2015 Update, so you probably have a newer compiler. ``asfloat`` doesn't really make sense for ``bool`` so I suspect it was a bug for it to accept it in the first place. It also fails to build with the Windows 10 SDK version.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Yes, I this is about the newer compilers. Why does it not make sense? What should I use instead?

Comment: bool is a logical true/false value, and asfloat converts a number to float. What is it you are trying to do exactly?

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn: I was using the `Function Overload float<x> asfloat(bool<x> value);` that is documented on MSDN and working in the older compilers. (Specifically I use `clip(asfloat(all(b4)))` to combine four clipping operations.) If you can confirm this is not supported anymore, I guess in my case I can simply change it to `clip(all(b4) ? 1.0 : -1.0)`, so no big deal. I'm just wondering why it disappeared and why it's not documented. Or maybe I misunderstood something?

Comment: I just filed a doc bug to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`asfloat(bool)` should never have worked. `asfloat` (and `asdouble`) is essentially the HLSL equivalent of `*reinterpret_cast<float*>(&x)`. This makes some sense on the integer data, but bool is problematic. The bit-field pattern of bool is ill-defined in HLSL so in theory it could be anything.

The compiler was updated somewhere in the Windows 8 era (i.e. post the DirectX SDK being declared legacy per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx)) to "fix" this behavior. The #43 legacy DirectX SDK version of the D3DCompiler DLL was the last released compiler to accept `asfloat` on a bool.

The MSDN page was never updated to reflect this, so I've filed a doc bug to correct that.